# Swizzle something that was retained

Tags: objective-c, method-swizzling

Hi all I don't understand `retain` so well.

There is this code here:

```
mAppIcon = [[NSImage imageNamed:@"NSApplicationIcon"] retain];
```

I am trying to swizzle it so whenever they ask for image with name `NSApplicationIcon` I give it my custom icon. I still see the original icon come back sometimes. I think it's because of this retain thing? Am I right? is it possible to clear the retain? This will make my swizzle works 100% of time instead of only 80% as it does now :(

I read here about `retain` but I wasnt able to apply it to help my situation above: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/assign-retain-copy-pitfalls-in-obj-c.html

Very specifically I am trying to swizzle this here: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/cocoa/nsMacDockSupport.mm?offset=200#140

Comment: That `retain` has nothing to do with it.   If you have the source to the project, why not just change the icon?

Comment: Thanks @bbum, it's an addon for firefox so people want to dynamically set their icon. So its interesting, it works if the user does it after startup, but on startup/restart of browser, it sets the icon but 5sec after it reverts. So temporarily I have a work around where I set the icon a second time wih a timeout of 10sec. What does that `retain` do btw?

Comment: It is a memory management primitive;  basically says that the object-- the image-- shouldn't go away.    If the icon is changing, then something else may be mucking with it.  I think NSApp has a -setApplicationIcon: method.  Put a breakpoint on that and see who else calls it.

Comment: Thanks @bbum ill investigate!